# why react component require refresh to load its content ,even after successful login?

Tags: reactjs, api, local-storage, access-token

In my react app after  successful login, i stored access and response token to local storage and set the token to axios header using axios intersaptor  than calling the get request to on another page give 401 error and after the refreshing the page it  works fine. So my problem is that , why it does not enter code here`work properly without refreshing.

login page

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import "./Login.css"
import api from "./Api.js"
export default function Login() {
  const [data,setdata]=useState([]);

 function handle(e){
     e.preventDefault();
   const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setdata({...data,[name]:value});
 }

function callapi(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(data);
    api.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/gettoken/',data)
    .then((res) =>{
        console.log(res.data);
        localStorage.setItem('access',res.data.access);
        localStorage.setItem('refresh',res.data.refresh);
    
       
    } ).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
        localStorage.removeItem('access');
        localStorage.removeItem('refresh');
      });
}


    return <><div className='container'>
        <form  className="formdiv">
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" onChange={handle} id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"/>
          <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" onChange={handle} id="exampleInputPassword1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1"/>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
        </div>
        <div className='butt'>
        <button type="submit" onClick={callapi} class="btn ">Submit</button></div>
      </form>
      </div>
      </>
    
}
```

api.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const api=axios.create({baseURL:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'});
const access=localStorage.getItem('access');
const refresh=localStorage.getItem('refresh');
api.interceptors.request.use(
    config =>{
        config.headers.authorization=`Bearer ${access}`;
        return config;
    },
    error=>{
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
export default api;
```

anathor component

```
import React ,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
import ImageCard from "./ImageCard";
import interviewImg from "./Images/interview.jpg";
import InterviewExperienceCard from "./InterviewExperienceCard";
import api from './Api.js';

function InterviewExperiencePage(){
  const [datalist,setdatalist] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  
    api.get('/experience/').then((res)=>{
      setdatalist(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    });
    
},[]);
```

Comment: try using axios.defaults.headers = {} logic instead of creating a instance of axios and using it everywhere else

Answer (score 0):

The issue here looks to be that you are setting you access and refresh token values before you login and then not permitting them to change. You can replace the values with functions.

```
const access = () => localStorage.getItem('access');
const refresh = () => localStorage.getItem('refresh');
api.interceptors.request.use(
    config =>{
        config.headers.authorization=`Bearer ${access()}`;
        return config;
    },
    error=>{
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

I would make the point that storing your access and refresh tokens and in localstorage is not good practice from a security point of view. I would probably store the access token just in memory while the refresh token should be a secure http only cookie. There are a lot of pitfalls with token security so I would advice doing a bit more research putting your code live.